# Swing's KeyStroke.getKeyStroke() returns UNKNOWN

Tags: java, swing, unicode, keystroke

The below character is a Russian language char

```java
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('П', ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK).getKeyCode(); // returns (int) 1055
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(1055, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK); //returns (javax.swing.KeyStroke) ctrl pressed UNKNOWN
```

But works for char like 'C'

```java
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('C', 2).getKeyCode(); // returns (int) 67
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(67, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK); //returns (javax.swing.KeyStroke) ctrl pressed C
```

Just way it shows for character 'C', How can I make it work for the Russian character.

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()` method on `KeyStroke` is concatenated from

- the modifiers text (ctrl, alt, ...)
- 'released' or 'pressed' depending on the `onKeyRelease` flag
- the VK (virtual key) text corresponding with with constant in `KeyEvent` (`AWTKeyStroke.getVKText(keycode)`)

All is well with your code, only the 'П' key has no corresponding `VK_` constant in the `KeyEvent` class. For a list of all recognized constants, see [KeyEvent Javadoc, Constants](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).

Do you want to extract the character corresponding with the key that was pressed?
In that case, use:

```
char c = (char) keyStroke.getKeyCode();
```

Comment: A key code is not a character.  That’s why the KeyEvent and KeyStroke classes have different methods for key codes and characters.

Comment: @Pater, Thanks. The use-case I have is, I have a menu option name starting with char 'П' and now I want to assign a short key for this menu option(in this case Ctrl + П), now in the menu i see something like this "П*****  Ctrl + Unknown keyCode: 0x41f". The same thing works fine for English because as you said, there is corresponding key for char 'C'